# Unlock screen by movement while an android phone is sleeping?

Tags: android, android-sensors, unlock

I am new here, but I really like to ask a question:

Is there a way to unlock an android phone by shaking while it's locked and sleeping? especially samsung devices, like Galaxy S3, S4 and Note series.

I've tried several apps, but none of them worked very correctly, it seems like after the power button is pressed, the sensors are also sleeping?

Thanks for any answer in advance.

Comment: Do you want to know how to do it through code or do you want an app to do it?

Comment: first concept proof, if there is some sample code, then it's perfect. :)

Comment: this is VERY battery demanding, you actually want your phone to be awake, an app like that is going to kill your battery life! it's really not that worthy, when phone is sleeping all sensors are sleeping (including touch screen) as long as they work they drain battery!

Comment: let's not worry about the battery for the moment, just discuss the possibility. we have some special situation need this to be possible.